Migrate pages with custom layout from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online
Hello i tried to migrate some pages from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online. Those pages are using a custom layout . This layout was deployed as a solution using .wsp. How can i migrate pages to sharepoint online as i dont have the .wsp anymore? I already tried using Sharegate but as in Sharepoint 2013 the custom layout was developped it failed trying to migrate the pages.
